# Open .sln file in a specific configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to open a solution for specific configuration(Debug|win32 or Release|64). My solution is very big and it takes a very long time to switch between configurations once inside the visual studio(and it often crashes even).

Comment: Could you provide your solution?

Comment: @EelLee - not sure what that would accomplish

Comment: Disable all plugins and try again. VS can handle very large (> 150 projects) ok (takes a minute to change over).

Comment: Open the .sln file in a text editor like Notepad.  Note the "ActiveCfg" setting.  You can easily write a little program that changes the value.

Comment: I have the ActiveCfg 320 times in my .sln file. I don't think visual studio picks the configuration it wants to open from that file.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to specify a default per se. However, I have been able to replace the list of configurations with a single item, so, in effect, that becomes the default.  I keep this modified version only in my workspace and do not check it into our source management.

In my case, for example I wanted to default to `Release|Any CPU`.

So, using a simple home-grown program, I update the `.sln` files and replaced the following:

```
**GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution**
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
    Dev|Any CPU = Dev|Any CPU
    QA|Any CPU = QA|Any CPU
    QA|x86 = QA|x86
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    Release|x86 = Release|x86
**EndGlobalSection**"
```

With the following:

```
**GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution**
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
**EndGlobalSection**
```

Now, when I open the solution `Release|Any CPU` is the first and only option.  When I want the other options, I retrieve the latest, unmodified version of source control or from a backup.

While this may seem as though it is more work than simply changing the selection each time the solution is open; it has other benefits:  I can update all our solutions at one time (our in-house update program scans and updates all `.sln` files in our code base), so I don't have to think about changing the configuration for every solution.  Further, when building a solution multiple times over the development cycle, this method eliminates the risk of forgetting to change the selection in any particular build. So, it is more reliable.

Comment: FWIW I launched once with `Release|x64` being the only option in `GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)`. Then exit Visual Studio 2015, reverted the section (to add back `Debug|x64` etc) and launched again and it launched again in Release and seems to have become the default (because of the clean exit?).

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the solution, I think there is a way to specify default configuration to load.
I don't believe there is any way to load a solution with a specific configuration.

Now, if your visual studio is crashing form simply trying to switch from one config to another, it is a whole new problem and I think you have to fix that one first.  Regardless of the size of a solution, it shouldn't crash.
Potentially, your configuration(or even a design of the application) has some problems. 
I have worked with applications that have millions of lines of code, and they never crashed because of config switch.

Here is a starting point for that:
[Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3675fsh6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Well, the solution has 320 projects. The crash happens usually because of Resharper. It is very inconvenient, because I have to turn off Resharper, change the configuration, enable the resharper. Even without the resharper(uninstalled it to test), the solution takes only two minutes to open, but switching configurations takes ~20 minutes. If I save the solution on a particular configuration, it opens fast, but switching again takes forever.